# How can i remove configurable product from cart in magento using SOAP API v1

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, api, soap, shopping-cart

I am using this code but it gives error "Call to a member function getId() on a non-object"

```
    $c = array(
                '272' => 25,
                '502' => 46
            );
    $arrProducts = array(
        array(
            'product_id' => $_REQUEST['product_id'],
            "super_attribute" => $c

        ),
    );

    $resultCartProductUpdate = $client->call($sess_id,'cart_product.remove',array($_REQUEST['CartID'],$arrProducts));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the arguments indicated by the API documentation:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.remove.html

There is no `super_attribute` key for `shoppingCartProductEntity`, you should use the `options` key instead.

You should replace `$arrProducts` with:

```
$arrProducts = array(
    array(
        'product_id' => $_REQUEST['product_id'],
        'options' => $c
    ),
);
```